# Convert "String" sqrt(#) into numerical value

Tags: regex, perl

I had to come up with a way to convert sqrt(#) into its actual numeric value because before I would have an array containing elements such as:

```
[sqrt(3), -sqrt(3), 1]
```

If I tried to multiply, I would get the error:

> Argument "-sqrt(3)" isn't numeric in multiplication (*)

Here is my work-around, but I think there's a better way. Any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#perl Solver.pl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $roots = "Sqrt[3] ||-Sqrt[3] ||1";
my @rootList = split(/ \|\|/, $roots); # fill array with string's values separated by " ||"


# Convert any Sqrt numbers to numerical value 
# (ex.) Sqrt[3] -> sqrt(3)
for $_ ( @rootList ){
    $_ =~ s/Sqrt\[/sqrt(/g; # Sqrt[ -> sqrt(
    $_ =~ s/\]/)/g; # ] -> )

    if( $_ =~ /-sqrt/ ){ # replace string of negative sqrt()
        my $temp = substr( $_, 6 ); # take "#)"
        $temp =~ s/\)//g; # remove ")"
        $_ = -1*sqrt( $temp );
    }
    elsif( $_ =~ /sqrt/ ){ # replace positive sqrt()
        my $temp = substr( $_, 5 );
        $temp =~ s/\)//g;
        $_ = sqrt( $temp );
    }
}

print "[@rootList]\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the use of `Sqrt[...]` to be cumbersome, why have the case in that format, and why have the `[]` style braces?

I would normally not recommend this, but a simple solution, if you trust, or can sanitize your inputs, is to just use the `eval` function.

```
for $_ ( @rootList ){
    $_ =~ s/Sqrt\[(.+)\]/sqrt($1)/;
    $_ = eval($_);
    $@ and die $@;
}
```

That does it..... all of it. Convert `Sqrt[...]` to `sqrt(...)`, and eval the result.

Comment: I receive the list of values from Mathematica output in bracket format and do some string manipulation to make it look nicer.  Thanks!  Nice solution.